# What is __LIBC_HIDDEN__ in C header?

Tags: android, c, libc, android-debug, bionic

### Introduction

In a log output of a crash, there is an error with backtrace output as:

```
#00 pc 00038cf0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__futex_wait_ex(void volatile*, bool, int, bool, timespec const*)+100)
```

I went to search for this file and is available in the link below:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/master/libc/private/bionic_futex.h

---

### Code

In this file there is the declaration of function **__futex_wait_ex **as:

```
static inline int __futex_wait_ex(volatile void* ftx, bool shared, int value) {
  return __futex(ftx, (shared ? FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET : FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE), value, nullptr,
                 FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY);
}
__LIBC_HIDDEN__ int __futex_wait_ex(volatile void* ftx, bool shared, int value,
                                    bool use_realtime_clock, const timespec* abs_timeout);
```

---

### Question

What **LIBC_HIDDEN**  does?

I seached in the internet some explanations but could not find an straight answer.
I was hopping that was a pattern used in my places so it would be easy to find.

Comment: I don't know *exactly* what it does, but I can say with >99% confidence that it is an implementation detail of Android libc that is *not* relevant to your problem. Whenever you have a crash inside the C library, your first hypothesis should be that the bug is in the code that *called* the C library, in this case probably four or five levels up the call stack.

Comment: In my case, it was a null pointer dereference at com.netflix.ninja process. Do you think it is an error in Netflix itself?

Comment: Yes. If you don't work for Netflix, you should probably report it to them and then forget about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a macro which is defined in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/a818445/libc/include/sys/cdefs.h

as

```
/* Used to tag non-static symbols that are private and never exposed by the shared library. */
#define __LIBC_HIDDEN__ __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
```

Basically it means that you can not use functions marked as **LIBC_HIDDEN** outside of the shared library they are implemented in.